# Apply converter throughout the whole project

Tags: jsf, converters

I would like to apply a `converter` to all my `h:outputText` in a project. Is there a way to do it for the whole project, so I don't have to repeat the tag for each field separately?

For example, assume I want the following converter.

```
<f:convertNumber type = "number" />
```

Is there a way not to repeat this for every `h:outputText` field that contains numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid but this is not possible.

But you could write your own JSF outputText Component. That's pretty easy:

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jsf/custom-component-basic.html

Comment: I actually just want the thousand separator for my number fields. Is this possible with customized components? I couldn't find anything regarding this matter.

Comment: Have you read the tutorial? You have to implement the encodeBegin method accordingly.